# Ajax get request with useless parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, parameters

I'm trying to execute next:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://127.0.0.1:6789/dir', 
data: "",   
success: function(data) { /*do something*/ },
dataType: 'html'
});
```

But when it executes, my server receives something like below:

```
http://127.0.0.1:6789/dir?_32567871112
```

I don't want to pass any parameters. What do I wrong?

Comment: Could be a cache-buster added automatically by your ajax library, to prevent that url from being cached.

Comment: How can I switch off it?

Comment: A query parameter is not going to affect the url being hit. `.../dir` is still going to be the script being requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, set `cache` to `true` in your `$.ajax` call's options.

jQuery adds that for cache breaking.

There is an option in jQuery to turn that off: (from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> `cache`
>
> Default: `true`, `false` for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp'
>
> If set to `false`, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the
>   browser. Setting cache to `false` also appends a query string parameter,
>   "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL.

Example with `cache` set to `true`:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  cache: true,
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:6789/dir',
  data: "",
  success: function (data) { /*do something*/
  },
  dataType: 'html'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation

If you look at cache parameter, you can see that it is adding a timestamp at the end of call in that format. If you want to get rid of it try to set cache to true, or type to POST(in case you dont want to allow cashing)

Answer (score 1):

I had ajaxSetup attribute in my code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
```

I commented it and it works now! 
Thanks.