# How to get script file by $.getScript()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to imported some javascript files from some code hosts.

```
    $.when(
        $.getScript('http://pingzi.googlecode.com/svn-history/r30/branches/wangqi/web/jquery.window.min.js'),
        $.getScript('http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/js/jquery.tablesorter.js'),
        $.getScript('http://tconnell.com/samples/scroller/lib/jquery.tablesorter.scroller.js'),
        $.getScript('http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js'), 
        $.Deferred(
            function(deferred) { 
                $(deferred.resolve);
            }
        )
    ).done(function() {  
       // my function goes here....
    });
```

When I try to call these URLs to import js files, the URLs will append `?_=1344036242417` and then I could not actually get to the script file I want.

i.e. 
`"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://pingzi.googlecode.com/svn-history/r30/branches/wangqi/web/jquery.window.min.js?_=1344036242417"`

Any one have ideas how to bypass this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What a great piece of code. +1 !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because caching in ajax is turned off by default in jQuery, to turn it on and remove the querystring do :

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 
    cache: true 
});
```

but that could also affect other ajax calls that you don't want to cache, there's a lot more on this in the [docs for getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/), and there's even a little how-to on creating a cached getScript function called cachedScript.

You can also enable caching in $.getScript by redefining the function with a new option to turn the cache on/off by passing true or false :

```
$.getScript = function(url, callback, cache){
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            success: callback,
            dataType: "script",
            cache: cache
    });
};
```

Comment: And now I'm getting downvoted ?

Comment: Thank you very much. I voted you up.

Answer (score 5):

`jQuery` have an automatic caching mechanism for such queries.
If you do not want the extra param to be added use following setup:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: true
});
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/#caching-requests

Answer (score 4):

jQuery is automatically adding the `_=1344036242417`, which breaks the URL.  Note:

- [Without the query param, the URL is fine](http://pingzi.googlecode.com/svn-history/r30/branches/wangqi/web/jquery.window.min.js)
- [But it 404s with the query param](http://pingzi.googlecode.com/svn-history/r30/branches/wangqi/web/jquery.window.min.js?_=1344036242417)

To prevent jQuery from adding that parameter: [Ajax get request with useless parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425215/ajax-get-request-with-useless-parameter). To summarize that answer, use `$.ajaxSetup` before calling `$.getScript()` to set `cache: true`.

> Be [*sic*] default, `$.getScript()` sets the cache setting to `false`. This appends a timestamped query parameter to the request URL to ensure that the browser downloads the script each time it is requested. You can override this feature by setting the cache property globally using [`$.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/):
>
> ```
> $.ajaxSetup({
>     cache: true
> });
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The appended query string is to prevent caching.  You can disable this by [enabling caching](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  cache: true
});
```

Comment: Ignore the syntax error for a moment; clearly the OP's code works to some degree beyond that given the 404 error.

Comment: Wow, really? 1. Post wrong answer 2. Get corrected 3. Delete answer 4. Correct answer to have the same content as the other two answers 5. Undelete and reap reputation. `*sigh*`

Comment: @MattBall sorry ... not intentional at all.  I wasn't looking at the other answers, just wanted to correct mine.